# Mahout seqdirectory mapreduce just gets one map task

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, mahout

I want to have more map tasks to increase parallelism of `Mahout seqdirectory` job. But every time I try, it creates just one map task.

- Hadoop version: 1.2.1
- Mahout version: 0.8/0.9 (tested, both not working for more map tasks)
- Scenario: lots of small files(about 566114 few KB files) store in HDFS

Before getting this problem (always one map task), I had faced another problem (GC overhead limit exceeded). Hence I had set more memory to solve it.

When I found that only one map task is getting spawned, I configured the Hadoop configuration file (`mapred-site.xml`,`hadoop-env.sh`...). I set `mapred.map.tasks` to `20` in `mapred-site.xml`. This did not help.

I found out that, the number of map tasks is decided by the number of chunks. In my case, total size of files is over 500 MB (bigger than default chunk size of 64 MB). I dug into Mahout source code (v0.9). I am not finding any solution.

Also, since I suspected that, the problem could be because of small files, I created two big files (2 500 MB files), and loaded them into HDFS, using `seqdirectory` command. But, still just one map task is launched.

I have no idea, how to solve this. Can someone with a knowledge of Hadoop and Mahout help me?

Note, I found someone contribute to this pb. note as mahout-833
I am tracing SequenceFileFromDirectory.java from Mahout 0.9 source code, try to figure out why.

Here is my configuration info: [job config file, hadoop config file(mapred-site.xml, hadoop-env.sh)](http://goo.gl/nf0IlB)

Comment: what is the command that you use to create your sequence file?